# AngularJS - change scope value when its key is true within another scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a ng-repeat like this

```
<li ng-repeat="car in cars">
  <p>{{car.model}}</p>
  <span ng-show="car.check"></span>
  <span ng-show="!car.check">X</span>
</li>
```

based on this `$scope.cars`

```
$scope.cars=[
    {'model':'Ford','check':true},
    {'model':'Honda','check':true},
    {'model':'Ferrari','check':true}
];
```

So when `check` is `true`, it is displayed a , and when it is false, a X

I have another `$scope.filter` (that I use for another purposes, but for the shake of simplicity I will just write its content)

```
$scope.filter = {
  "producers": {
    "Ford": true,
    "Honda": true,
    "Ferrari": false
    }
}
```

What I would like is whenever I change the `$scope.filter` values, that change would be reflected in the `$scope.cars` (so in this example, if `filter.producers.Ferrari:false`, the corresponding element in `$scope.cars`would automatically change as well to `'check':false`

You can check the [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/vq6f8002/) Thanks in advance!

Edit: as RipTheJacker says, the question is about how to make a function that updates the cars checked value based on the filter values.

Comment: Where do you change that `$scope.filter`? It seems you could achieve this just by iterating through `$scope.cars` with the producer change or all `$scope.filter`

Comment: IRL I change it through some checkboxes, but I didn't add that to the example in order to make it easier to understand. So I would like just to change manually the values in $scope.filter, and that it automatically affects the corresponding value in $scope.cars

Comment: Might want to update your question for clarity. The real question was how to make a function that updates the cars checked value based on the filter values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

I missed the original requirement to update the value. The easiest way is to watch the `filter` model from your scope:

```
$scope.$watch("filter", function(nv,ov){
  angular.forEach($scope.cars, function(car){
    car.check = nv.producers[car.model]
  })
}, true)
```

Comment: As I understand his question, I think he would like to **modify** the value according to his filter.

Comment: Yea, was about to delete. Writing a new answer right now in his JS fiddle

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as @Mistalis says, I would need to modify the value within the cars scope when the value in the producers scope is changed

Comment: Perfect, that solves it, and I think is the best approach, so I will mark it as valid. I updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/x1jxatrr/

Answer (score 1):

I've updated your [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yfn9k7n2/).

Basically just updated your `$scope.checkProducerTrue` function to:

```
$scope.checkProducerTrue = function(c) {
   angular.forEach($scope.filter.producers, function(value, key) {
       if (key == c.model) c.check = value;
   });
};
```

Comment: Perfect! That was I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

With Angulars'  $scope.$watch you can "listen" changes in variables.
I leave you a very simple example based on your JSFiddle... you should optimize the function but i think the idea is clear.

```js
  $scope.$watch('filter.producers',function(s){
 $scope.cars[0].check = $scope.filter.producers.Ford;
  $scope.cars[1].check = $scope.filter.producers.Honda;
  $scope.cars[2].check = $scope.filter.producers.Ferrari;
},true)
```

[Link to JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/h083kqow/)

Comment: I think this is probably the best approach, but the problem is that I don't know the content of $scope.filters.producers in advance (so it could be as well another different brand), so I wouldn't be able to write the rules like this :(

Comment: If you know the "cars" format (array of JSON), and the filter format, you can just use javascript to compare the cars model with the filter model and take the filters value.

Comment: If you have more information about those formats, we can make a generic function that parses both arrays and matches the values, so dont be shy and share it with us

Comment: The answer provided by RipTheJacker already solves the problem with this approach. Thanks for the help!