# AngularJs - <ul> <li> element to top when its checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This question is based in [this previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40891952/angularjs-change-scope-value-when-its-key-is-true-within-another-scope)

I have a `ng-repeat` like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="opt in namesCtrl.uniqueCars">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="namesCtrl.filter['cars'][opt.element]" | orderBy:['checkbox','-count']"><p2>{{opt.element}} ({{opt.count}})</p2>
</li>
```

Where the elements are taken from `this.uniqueCars`

```
this.uniqueCars=[
    {'element':'Ford','count':3,'checkbox':false},
    {'element':'Honda','count':2,'checkbox':false},
    {'element':'Ferrari','count':1,'checkbox':false},
    {'element':'Delorean','count':6,'checkbox':false}
];
```

And the checked items in the view go to `this.filter` (that I use for another purpose)

```
this.filter = {
    "cars": {}
}
```

So what I want to achieve is to order the checkbox list in the view, so when one of the items is checked, it would go to the top, something like this

[image]

[image]

In order to do that, I have a `$watch` that goes like this

```
$scope.$watch("namesCtrl.filter", function(nv,ov){
    angular.forEach(self.uniqueCars, function(opt){
    opt.checkbox = nv.cars[opt.element]
    })
}, true)
```

But the behavior is pretty inconsistent when ordering by the checkbox value (when first clicking it does the job, OK, but when unclicking it doesn't work, and when clicking again it sorts it in the opposite way).

So I would like to do this by modifying the `$watch`. (I do it this way as IRL `this.filter` could be modified by other elements, so I need to watch the changes there).

PS: the `this.uniqueCars.checkbox` the field is inserted by me just in order to make the sorting possible, so it would be safe to modify it.

You can check the working [Plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/3tFJ4HUOYOv5EvYLME9V?p=preview).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost got it right.
There was a small problem with your `$watch` function: In the case where a car is not yet a member of `namesCtrl.filter`, its `checkbox` value is removed from `namesCtrl.uniqueCars` because it's undefined.
If you handle this case like this:

```
$scope.$watch("namesCtrl.filter", function(nv,ov){
  angular.forEach(self.uniqueCars, function(opt){
    var value = nv.cars[opt.element] ? nv.cars[opt.element].checkbox : false;
    opt.checkbox = value;
  });
}, true);
```

Then your ordering is fine. Except you also need to order by checkbox in reverse order:

```
<li ng-repeat="opt in namesCtrl.uniqueCars | orderBy:['-checkbox','-count']">
```

See [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PVRXNKJzjvAu9NmpD6GB?p=preview).

Comment: Works perfect, that was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you modify `checkbox` propery itself? Changing input's model to `opt.checkbox` and commenting watch out make everything work. I think it's better this way.

But you can modify `opt.checkbox = nv.cars[opt.element]` to `opt.checkbox = !!nv.cars[opt.element]` to make it work too (the checkbox property in `cars` object is `undefined`, that breaks proper ordering).

Comment: This solution is correct as well. I marked the other as correct as it was chronologically the first, and I cannot tell if one way is preferable than the other. Thanks anyway!